# onbeforeunload issue with Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, alert, confirmation

In last days I noticed that the confirmation alert that I supposed to see before leaving my website page is no more shown on Chrome and Firefox, but it's displayed on IE.
If I debug with Google Chrome Dev Tools, I can see that function confirm is executed, enters the if statement, but no alert box is displayed. I tried to restart Google Chrome and look for an option to reset alert messages, but I didn't find nothing.
Any ideas?

The code is this:

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
                    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', confirm, false);
                }
                else window.attachEvent("onbeforeunload", confirm);

...

function confirm(e) {
    if (changed== true) {
        return "You haven't saved your changes!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a working solution, but actually I don't understand why the attachEvent isn't working anymore. Anyway, this is the working solution, tested on IE, Chrome and Firefox:

I removed the addEventListener and attachEvent lines:

```
/* if (window.addEventListener) {
                    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', confirm, false);
                }
                else window.attachEvent("onbeforeunload", confirm); */
```

In the HTML, I add the attribute onbeforeunload to the body tag:

```
<body onbeforeunload="return confirmEvent()">
```

I also renamed the onbeforeunload function to avoid confusion with the confirm built-in javascript function:

```
function confirmEvent(e) {
    if (changed== true) {
        return "You haven't saved your changes!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this work if the browser is closing due to OS shutdown?

Answer (score 1):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
  var confirmationMessage = "\o/";

  e.returnValue = confirmationMessage;     // Gecko and Trident
  return confirmationMessage;              // Gecko and WebKit
});
```

Worked in every Browser i tested ;)

PS: I know its a little bit late